# OpenLayers vector tile rendering problem on .NET Core 2.2

Tags: postgis, openlayers, c#, .net, vector-tiles

I working on OpenLayers vector tile. I am using PostGIS ST_AsMvt function for render my geom data.

I sending query like this to PostgreSQL in my .NET Core server

```
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvt, 'geom', 4096, 'geom')
     FROM (
             SELECT
                    I.gid,
                    I.fid,
             ST_AsMVTGeom(
                    I.geom,
                  st_makeenvelope(minX, minY,maxX , maxY),
                     4096,
                     256,
                     false
             ) as geom
             FROM public."GeomTable" I
             WHERE I.geom && st_makeenvelope(minX, minY,maxX , maxY)
             AND ST_Intersects(I.geom,st_makeenvelope(minX, minY,maxX , maxY))) mvt;
```

and just returning as response byte array data. But getting type error while OpenLayers parse this data to PBF.

```
Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 7 at Pbf.skip
Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 4 at Pbf.skip
Uncaught Error: Unimplemented type: 3 at Pbf.skip
```

My VectorTileLayer object;

```
var mvtVectorLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
        declutter: false,
        source: new VectorTileSource({
          format: new MVT(),
          url: "https://localhost:5001/{z}/{x}/{y}"

        }),
        style: new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: "red",
            width: 1
          })
        })
      });
```

So I am so confused about solution . I have done a lot of research but I don't get any solution.

**Example data from DB**

> 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

I am getting byte array data from db but when i return it as response , browser automatically convert to base64 string.

Comment: Can you show how the data from the DB looks like on the frontend?

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SOLUTION

I was responding to the browser as bytes

`return (byte[]datas);`

so i change response type to File and works fine

`return File(datas, "application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile");`